# scala - how to access a case class method from another class?

Tags: scala

Initially I had a case class inside an object. So I could call `extractSales` method from another class like this: `SaleProcessor.extractSales(salesJson)`.

```
object SaleProcessor {
 case class Sale(name: String, type: String, description: String) {
 def extractSales(salesJson: JValue): Seq[Sale] = {
    salesJson.extract[Seq[Sale]]
  }}}
```

Then I read somewhere that there is no need to nest a case class inside an object and decided to remove the `SaleProcessor` object leaving just the case class. But after that I'm unable to call the method like before.

As far as I understand without an object I have to instantiate the case class. But not sure how to achieve this since the Sale object is created at the moment if extraction from JSON?

Another question is what would be the most adequate approach with nesting case classes into objects and what is considered the best practice in Scala?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'd still keep the method inside the `object` and call it the same way:

```
case class Sale(name: String, type: String, description: String)

object SaleProcessor {
  def extractSales(salesJson: JValue): Seq[Sale] = ...
}

// elsewhere
SaleProcessor.extractSales(salesJson)
```

It would be common to name the object the same as the class (i.e. `object Sale` instead of `object SaleProcessor`), making it a companion object, but not necessary.

Comment: Creating a companion object for the case class is a great solution. But I'm curious what are the possible use cases if any for nesting a case class inside an object? Or is this just a bad practice?

Comment: No, it isn't particularly good or bad practice. It's just another way to group classes, and whether the class you group together is a case class doesn't matter at all. You can see http://wiki.c2.com/?WhenToUseInnerClasses for some guidance, it applies pretty much the same to Scala as to Java.